# Carbon dioxide sensor MG 811

Tags: esp8266, c++, analogread, oled, calibration

I am using MG811 carbon dioxide sensor with ESP8266 module. CO2 values is being read inside closed room. The value comes around 400 ppm. Using CO2 generator does not make increase in reading. Checked with pSense RH co2 Temp handheld meter. It shows around 750-800 ppm. But ESP8266 still shows around 420 ppm on oled display.

```
#include "CO2Sensor.h"
CO2Sensor co2Sensor(A0, 0.99, 100);

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("=== Initialized ===");
co2Sensor.calibrate();
}

void loop() {
int val = co2Sensor.read();
Serial.print("CO2 value: ");
Serial.println(val);
delay(1000);
}
```

What is the meaning of (A0, 0.99, 100) in second line of code. Is any calibration needs to be done for correct value ?

Comment: You will probably need to show this thing is wired and what source you are using to power the heating element.

Comment: check the library documentation

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears to come from an example in the library you are using https://github.com/solvek/CO2Sensor/blob/master/examples/ReadCO2/ReadCO2.ino

To answer your questions:

***What is the meaning of (A0, 0.99, 100) in second line of code.***
Inspection of the library source code shows:
CO2Sensor::CO2Sensor(int analogPin, float inertia, int tries)

Of course, if you don't understand how the library is using the variables inertia and tries, this alone will make no sense to you.

***Is any calibration needs to be done for correct value ?***

In my opinion, the answer is YES. Furthermore, I think that calibration is necessary but not sufficient to appropriately use the sensor to the extent that you can have a good idea about what a "correct value" means.

I like that you get the fundamental idea of testing, or validating, a sensor. I like the idea that you are using another monitor (assuming it is a good one) as a "standard" and I like that you use a CO2 generator - assuming you are doing that safely.

What is lacking, again, in my opinion, is any understanding of how the sensor works. It is not that I am an expert on this particular sensor, but even a brief look at what passes as a data sheet https://sandboxelectronics.com/files/SEN-000007/MG811.pdf and the text of the library usage https://github.com/solvek/CO2Sensor and a few other sources that are freely available; makes it clear to me that you need to dig into this much more before you will have success understanding and appropriately using this sensor.

It is complicated. I hope that my response is not off putting and instead points you in the right direction.